# putting 2 programs together

Tags: c++

i made 2 programs.
first one converts a HEX to a dec.
second one converts a dec to a bin.

now i want to put them together that first converts a hex to dec and then from dec to bin
but how can i do that?

thanks.

HEX to dec

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void decToBin( int, int );
int main(void)
{


char s[] = "ff";
unsigned long x;
x = strtoul(s, 0, 16);
printf("%s"
"%lu"
"\n"
, s, x, x, x);

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

dec to bin

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void decToBin( int, int );

int main()
{
int decimal;
cin >> decimal;  
decToBin( decimal, 2 ); 
system  ("pause");
return 0; 
}
void decToBin(int num, int base)
{
if (num > 0)
{
    decToBin(num/base, base);
    cout<< num % base;
}
}
```

Comment: You should precise more what you mean by putting them together.

Comment: your functions really should do just one thing (now you're doing both conversion *and* printing)

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipe to pass the stdout of the first program to stdin of the second:

hex2dec number | dec2bin

This should work from the command line in shell, install Cygwin Bash if you are in Windows.

Comment: You **can** use the pipe on Windows `cmd.exe`!

Comment: how can i do this? can you lend me a hand?

Comment: After you've compiled the two you have two executables... Open cmd.exe if you are in Windows (Win-R and type cmd or cmd32). Type this on the command line: hex2dec 0x4545 | dec2bin. Assuming the first class compiled as hex2dec and the second as dec2bin.

Comment: ... and assuming they are in the system path (very unlikely)